# The plugins `advance_pdf_viewer, flutter_webview_plugin` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, kotlin

The plugins `advance_pdf_viewer, flutter_webview_plugin` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of
Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs."

I follow some documentation but is still not working.
i upgrade and downgrade my version but still not working.
should I share my mainActivity.kt and manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

if there is no newer version of `advance_pdf_viewer, flutter_webview_plugin` available with the new android V2 embedding, your can't do anything inside of your app. Keep watching for plugin updates of these 2 plugins... or go to it's github project and open an issue to fix it. Sometime the master branch has already fix it. In this case you could try to link direct to the master branch and not to a version in pub.dev

Answer (score 0):

for advance_pdf_viewer i use  `$flutter pub add advance_pdf_viewer`
This will add a line like this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` (and run an implicit flutter pub get):

```
dependencies:
  advance_pdf_viewer: ^2.0.1
```

Alternatively, your editor might support or flutter pub get. Check the docs for your editor to learn more.

Import it
Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';
```

and for webview I try dependencies:

```
  flutter_webview_plugin:
    git: https://github.com/nuc134r/flutter_webview_plugin.git
```

and it all works for me than you.